# Flutter Hot Reload is broken on Android Studio 3.1 and above

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I updated to Android Studio 3.1.1 recently and since then I started minor issues with Flutter **Hot Reload** but restarting Android Studio appears to fix it temporarily. However, about a couple of days ago, **Hot Reload** stopped working entirely. For example, this is my terminal output:

```
gap@xop:~/Flutter/Projects/fibo$ flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on HTC 10 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                       1.0s
Resolving dependencies...                                   11.0s
Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...                           2.8s
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk (31.9MB).
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...                  7.8s
```

It just ends there, the usual information about using `r` or `R` for hot reload or full rebuild is no longer there. Also, I don't see the logs for the app in Logcat but I can see all logs if I select **No Filters**.

**What I have done:**

1. Upgraded to Android Studio 3.2 Canary 11
2. Switched Flutter to master and subsequently ran `git pull`, `flutter upgrade` and `flutter doctor`
3. Restarted Android Studio
4. Did full system restart.

**Android Studio Info:**

```
Android Studio 3.2 Canary 11
Build #AI-181.3007.14.32.4720098, built on April 13, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.13.0-38-generic
```

**Flutter info:**

```
Flutter 0.3.3-pre.13 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision fd7222eea8 (11 hours ago) • 2018-04-23 02:03:46 +0100
Engine • revision cb3376c5de
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.48.0.flutter-fe606f890b
```

**System Info:**

Ubuntu 17.04

Please, is there any fix for this?

Comment: Create an issue on [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter)

Comment: @RémiRousselet I have thought of it but I don't know if the source of the problem is Android Studio or Flutter itself.

Comment: That's not a problem. They'll investigate and act accordingly.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thanks. I have raised the issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16881

Answer (score 1):

These steps got the hot restart button working for me in Android Studio:

From your project directory, in the terminal window run the following commands:

1. `flutter emulators`
2. `flutter emulators --launch <<your emulator name>>`
3. `flutter attach`
4. Run project in debug mode

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue after the refactoring project. I try several solutions but nothing helps. then a few hours of review my source I find a solution. 
So in my case on some reason when I move one of my custom widget from one folder to other

I got import like this

```
import 'D:dev/projectname/app/common/bottom_navigation.dart';
```

instead of this one

```
import 'package:app/common/bottom_navigation.dart';
```

fix incorrect import solve my problem.

not sure is this case can happen very often, but put it here, maybe it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure flutter doctor does not display any issues.
2. Try running the app by clicking on the Debug button instead of Run button [View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87PTH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I'm using Unbuntu 19.04, and I began to test Flutter, installing all dependencies, Android Studio, SDK, etc.

- first issue: I had forgotten this command:

  ```
  flutter doctor --android-licenses
  ```
- second issue: I had a jdk-10, and I didn't know this was the problem. So I installed the openjdk-8-jdk, remove the previous one and voilá.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
  ```